# quad edge data structure makeEdge logic

Tags: java, data-structures, computational-geometry

I was going through the Guibas-Stolfi paper which describes a quad-edge data structure which can be used to compute Delaunay Triangulations. I am using java to implement the QuadEdge data structure.

I was following the implementation mentioned on this website [Quad Edge data Structure Java](http://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/maxia/CS252/).

To summarize in short, the Quad edge structure comprises of 2 operations namely

1. makeEdge -> Returns an Quad Edge for an edge e present in a sub-division
2. splice(a,b) -> A function which is used to change the topology associated with quad edges a and b.

Now, the Quad Edge data structure consists of 2 fields namely Data and Next pointer.

The next field is calculated by using the formula,
   e[r].Next = e(Rot^r)Onext.

For an idea about Onext, I am attaching a figure from the Guibas-Stolfi paper

[image: Edge Functions]

Now, the sample code sets the next pointers for all the 4 parts of the quad edge. They are set as follows [1](http://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/maxia/CS252/),

```
q0 = new QuadEdge();
q1 = new QuadEdge();
q2 = new QuadEdge();
q3 = new QuadEdge();

q0.Onext = q0; 
q1.Onext = q3; //on the sphere, left=right (How?? or Why??)
q2.Onext = q2; 
q3.Onext = q1;
```

My question was if Onext i.e(next counter-clockwise edge having the same origin as e) is the edge itself, why is it the other edge when the dual edge is taken.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like both q1 and q3 have origin at the same point (dummy point at infinity). That's why `q1.oNext == q3` and `q3.oNext == q1`.

Answer (score 0):

The links in the question are broken, but fortunately
it contains enough information in its body.

Quad-edge data structure was introduced in the paper [Primitives for the Manipulation of General
Subdivisions and the Computation of Voronoi
Diagrams](http://www.sccg.sk/%7Esamuelcik/dgs/quad_edge.pdf) by LEONIDAS GUIBAS and JORGE STOLFI. And I think it contains the answer on your question.

Four edge records `QuadEdge` (two oppositely directed edges of primal graph and two oppositely directed edges of dual graph) constitute a group corresponding to an edge in the subdivision:

[image: Quad-edge]

An arrow on the picture points on the next edge sharing the same origin (same vertex for primal edges and same face for dual edges) - `Onext`.

`MakeEdge` function constructs a sphere subdivision, containing one undirected edge, one face and two vertices:

[image: MakeEdge in Quad-Edge data structure]

`q0` and `q2` are oppositely oriented edges of primal graph, with an origin in a vertex. And since there is only one directed edge from each vertex, we have: `q0.Onext = q0` and `q2.Onext = q2`.

`q1` and `q3` are oppositely oriented edges of dual graph, and they are loop-edges since their origin and destination are in the same (and the only) face of the subdivision. This face is the origin of both `q1` and `q3`, so their `oNext`s form a cycle:

```
q1.Onext = q3;
q3.Onext = q1;
```

Please note that both operations `makeEdge` and `splice` make sense for half-edge data structure as well. One can find their implementation in e.g. [MeshLib](https://github.com/MeshInspector/MeshLib#readme), see
`MeshTopology::makeEdge()` and `MeshTopology::splice( EdgeId a, EdgeId b )`.